# use xml-rpc for ssl enabled sites

Tags: php, ssl, xml-rpc

I want to connect xml-rpc site that use ssl cerfification. But i can't call basic file_get_contents() due to the SSL certification of xml-rpc site. How can I disable php ssl check without using Curl.

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use cURL?

Comment: I have an example php script to connect xml-rpc site so I want to use basic php codes if possible.

Comment: I think using cURL would be the best solution.

Comment: hey can any post a sample using curl